# Why use () as the hash?

Tags: ruby

I saw some hash like the following in some .rb configuration file

```
cache( :path => "#{currentDir}/cache" )
```

why not using {}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cache is a method, syntax like

```
      method( a => b , c => d )
```

is a shorthand (syntactic sugar) for

```
       method({ a => b , c => d})
```

Answer (score 2):

In ruby, if the only argument of a method is a hash, the braces are assumed.

**edit** To clear it up: `cache()` is a method, which takes a hash as its argument, probably like this:

```
def cache(*args)
   # ...
end
```

Comment: Well, because that doesn't make sense. The braces are to encapsulate the keys and values of a hash. In that example, you only have the braces around the value.

Comment: This doesn't only work if the hash is the _only_ argument. If the _last_ argument is a hash, you can leave of the braces. Also the signature would be more along the lines of `def cache(opts = {})` at least in Rails.